# Positiong img under secondary img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem again. I need positioning img (button) under news img. Here is link : [HERE](http://i.gavrecky.sk/index2.php)

Comment: What have you tried? Even though you posted a link I would still consider posting some of the relevant HTML/CSS to make this question more accessible. (Also for the future, when your site may change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
img {
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

> You were getting problem because display of "img" and "a" was inline(no line feed) by default.
>   Set display of any one of them to block.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `anchor` tag which contains the `button` style property - `display: block`